# what's differnce between push() and callback in nodejs Transform

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, nodejs-stream

i'm implementing a [Transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamtransform) which is piped by mongoose cursor (which works like readable stream, (or maybe it's real readable stream))

```js
const myTransform = new Transform({
  readableObjectMode: true,
  writableObjectMode: true,
  transform(chunk: Document, encoding, callback) {
    this.push(chunk?.toObject() ?? null); // <- transforms data
    callback(); // <- calls callback
  },
});

MyMongooseModelWithHugeData.find()
  .cursor()
  .pipe(myTransform)
  .pipe(someWriteStream)
```

Yup. My current code works fine.

But I found out the `callback` inside `transform` implementation, receives second parameter (which looks like classic nodejs async callback style obviously).

So, I changed my code like below, and found out that it also works fine..

```js
const myTransform = new Transform({
  readableObjectMode: true,
  writableObjectMode: true,
  transform(chunk: Document, encoding, callback) {
    callback(null, chunk?.toObject() ?? null); // <- transforms data and calls callback.
  },
});
```

And I felt somthing awkward. I've search some blogs about creating Transform stream. And all articles that I found was telling same that I have to use `this.push()` and call `callback()`.
But none of them did even mention about the second parameter of `callback()`.

So, my question is:

- Is there's difference between `this.push()` and `callback()` when passing transformed value?
- Why many people recommend using `this.push` instead of `callback` ?

Comment: They are semantically identical when forwarding a single chunk. However, `push()` may be called multiple times, while `callback()` must be called only once. I tend to use `callback(null, obj)` when only forwarding a single chunk and, otherwise, repeated `push(obj)` + `callback()` when relaying multiple chunks per handler execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from nodejs documantation

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/stream.md#transform_transformchunk-encoding-callback

It is possible that no output is generated from any given chunk of input data.

The `callback` function must be called only when the current chunk is completely
consumed. The first argument passed to the `callback` must be an `Error` object
if an error occurred while processing the input or `null` otherwise. If a second
argument is passed to the `callback`, it will be forwarded on to the
`transform.push()` method.

**In other words, the following are equivalent:**

```js
transform.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, callback) {
  this.push(data);
  callback();
};

transform.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, callback) {
  callback(null, data);
};
```